# SQL Incorrect syntax near the keyword then & if

Tags: sql-server

SQL Error with the below code, what should I be using.

> Severity: Error, Text: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As for the error, `IF` is a logical flow operator, it doesn't go in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: `IF` is a statement not an expression, use `IIF` or `CASE` instead

Comment: This syntax is valid for mysql, but won't work in sql-server. Use CASE instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `CASE` for this purpose

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Kit_issue.JobRealeased = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO'
    END AS 'Calculated_ReleasedJob'
...
```

Comment: should of known that my self!

Comment: No problem, we are here to help :) And please accept my answer if was help you.